# How to make xls charts?

Tags: c++, excel, xls

I'm trying to export application data as xls chart.

I'm doing it using [SimpleXlsxWriter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexlsx/).
But I have some problems with this lib.

---

Here's what I got using this lib

```
#include <Xlsx/Workbook.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace SimpleXlsx;

    CWorkbook book;
    CWorksheet &data = book.AddSheet("Data");

    std::vector<CellDataDbl> header = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 8 };
    std::vector<CellDataDbl> data1  = { 2, 6, 4, 8, 5 };
    std::vector<CellDataDbl> data2  = { 5, 3, 5, 2, 4 };

    data.AddRow(header);
    data.AddRow(data1);
    data.AddRow(data2);

    CChartsheet &chart = book.AddChart("Chart", CHART_BAR);
    chart.SetBarDirection(CChartsheet::BAR_DIR_VERTICAL);
    chart.SetBarGrouping(CChartsheet::BAR_GROUP_STACKED);
    chart.SetTableDataState(CChartsheet::TBL_DATA);
    chart.SetLegendPos(CChartsheet::EPosition::POS_TOP);

    CChartsheet::Series ser1;
    ser1.valAxisFrom = CellCoord(1, 0);
    ser1.valAxisTo   = CellCoord(1, data1.size() - 1);
    ser1.valSheet    = &data;
    ser1.title       = "Ser1";

    CChartsheet::Series ser2;
    ser2.valAxisFrom = CellCoord(2, 0);
    ser2.valAxisTo   = CellCoord(2, data2.size() - 1);
    ser2.valSheet    = &data;
    ser2.title       = "Ser2";

    chart.AddSeries(ser1);
    chart.AddSeries(ser2);

    book.Save("test.xls");
}
```

[image: Test.png]

I didn't find the ways how to show y-axes, show horizontal lines, set x-axes values, insert the chart into the data sheet, etc.

---

Here's what do I want to get as a result
[image: Test1.png]

---

What a library can help me or how can I get a required result? Maybe SimpleXlsxWriter can do that?

Comment: Take a look at [**`this`**](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-set-y-axis) link.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want from the SimpleXlsxWriter, just with a few modifications of your code. Briefly:

- save with SimpleXlsxWriter's format `.xlsx` not `.xls`
- Add a category axis to one of your series and set it to first data row
- use `BAR_GROUP_PERCENT_STACKED` since you want the y axis to be on % scale
- You can control the order you add the series the the chart, to get the order you want in the bottom table

Consider this code, suggested modifications are indicated in comments:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace SimpleXlsx;

    CWorkbook book;
    CWorksheet &data = book.AddSheet("Data");

    std::vector<CellDataDbl> header = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 8 };
    std::vector<CellDataDbl> data1  = { 2, 6, 4, 8, 5 };
    std::vector<CellDataDbl> data2  = { 5, 3, 5, 2, 4 };

    data.AddRow(header);
    data.AddRow(data1);
    data.AddRow(data2);

    CChartsheet &chart = book.AddChart("Chart", CHART_BAR);
    chart.SetBarDirection(CChartsheet::BAR_DIR_VERTICAL);
    chart.SetBarGrouping(CChartsheet::BAR_GROUP_PERCENT_STACKED); // <-- seems you want this format?
    chart.SetTableDataState(CChartsheet::TBL_DATA);
    chart.SetLegendPos(CChartsheet::EPosition::POS_TOP);

    chart.SetYAxisGrid(CChartsheet::EGridLines::GRID_MAJOR); // <-- to draw the horizontal lines 

    CChartsheet::Series ser1;
    ser1.valSheet    = &data;
    ser1.valAxisFrom = CellCoord(1, 0);
    ser1.valAxisTo   = CellCoord(1, data1.size() - 1);
    ser1.title       = "Ser1";

    // Now add a category axis from your the first row of the data sheet
    ser1.catAxisFrom = CellCoord(0, 0);
    ser1.catAxisTo = CellCoord(0, data1.size() - 1);
    ser1.catSheet    = &data;

    CChartsheet::Series ser2;
    ser2.valSheet    = &data;
    ser2.valAxisFrom = CellCoord(2, 0);
    ser2.valAxisTo   = CellCoord(2, data2.size() - 1);
    ser2.title       = "Ser2";

    // insert the series in the order you want from the bottom up in the chart's table
    chart.AddSeries(ser2);   
    chart.AddSeries(ser1);

    book.Save("c:\\so\\test.xlsx"); // <-- Save as xlsx, not xls
}
```

[image: Resulting Chart]

Comment: Adding a category axis works well. What about y-values on the left side and horizontal lines?

Comment: The horizontal lines can be drawn using `chart.SetYAxisGrid(GRID_MAJOR);` (I added that to the code. Use GRID_MINOR for a more dense grid). For the Y axis sorry I did not get exactly what you want to do, dont you have an axis at all? or you mean that you want to control the labels? because it seems that the control over that is somehow limited.

Comment: I mean showing y-values and horizontal lines like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMy7i.png. Now I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLBVk.png and I'm afraid that your last edit didn't solve it.

Comment: We're not getting the same thing with the same code. That's a bit weird. I attached an image to what I'm getting with the above code.

Comment: MSVC-2015. I copied and pasted your code. Here is my result https://imgur.com/a/PlgaR

Comment: Isn't the Y axis hidden or something? Did you try to "move" the chart object to the right? Or to shrink it?

Comment: No. But vertical lines can be showed. Maybe I downloaded different version of SimpleXlsxWriter. Do you know can we place data and chart in one sheet?

Comment: Obviously not with the SimpleXlsxWriter. Want my advice? Dont work directly with Excel from C++, that's simply a *pain*. From my experience, just interface your C++ code with Excel via `CSV` files, and there are techniques that permit you to get what you want in an Excel sheet, *automatically* (using some templates and a few lines of VBA). I will be glad to answer if you ask a dedicated question about this. :) (no need for a bounty just tag me :D)